# MIPS - Storing integers in memory (label)

Tags: assembly, mips

The problem is as stated below. I think I have somewhat working solution. However, I don't really utilize the label (array) to store my integer. My program currently stores the first integer of 0 at 1000000 (memory address), but I'm not sure that's the right place. Is there any way that I can store my integer at "array"? Note that I cannot use pseudo-instruction such as la.

**Problem:**

> Write a program that stores the number 0 in the first four bytes of the .data section, then stores the number 1 in the next four bytes, then stores the number 2 in the four bytes after that and so on. Do this for numbers 0 through 24.
>
> Of course you will do this in a counting loop. The address in the data section is contained in a base register. Increment the base register each time a number is stored.
>
> The data section of your program should look like
>
> ```
>      .data
>       array:   .space    100
> ```

**My solution:**

```
    .text
    .globl main

main:

ori     $8, $0, 0       # counter 
ori     $9, $0, 25      # counter bound
lui     $10, 0x1000     # initialize memory address


loop:
beq     $8, $9, exit    # exit if counter = 25  
sll     $0, $0, 0
sw      $8, 0($10)  # store integer 
sll     $0, $0, 0 
addiu   $8, $8, 1       # increment counter 
addiu   $10, $10, 4     # increment memory address  

j loop                  # while loop
sll     $0, $0, 0 

exit:
sll     $0, $0, 0


.data
array:  .space 100      # reserve 100 bytes. each integer is 4 bytes. to reserve 25 integers
```

Comment: What about `lui     $10, array`?

Comment: Jonathon - that gives me a syntax error.

Comment: You can easily verify the address of `array` in a simulator like SPIM/MARS. Of course, that address may only be valid for that particular simulator, but I'm assuming that's fine if you're given pointless limitations like no use of  `la`.

Comment: Use `la`, assemble, disassemble, rewrite `la` by the assembler original output. When I write MIPS asm for some SO questions, I try to avoid pseudo instructions just for the fun challenge of it, but avoiding `la` is sort of stupid, can't think of any good reason, except having bad MIPS assembler, then you can switch assembler itself.

Comment: BTW, wasn't that limitation meant as you should not use `la` inside the loop, i.e. you should work with "base address" already in register, addressing next element of loop from previous one? That would make sense, and look as valid limitation to force student to produce more reasonable code. But the initial load...